ERROR [client internal] load build context using Docker in WSL
I am getting the following error:
Here is the full error:
 => [client node 1/1] FROM docker.io/library/node:16.14-alpine@sha256:28bed508446db2ee028d08e76fb47b935defa26a849  0.0s
 => ERROR [client internal] load build context                                                                    31.8s
 => => transferring context: 380.22MB                                                                             31.8s
 => CACHED [client client-local-build 1/4] WORKDIR /app                                                            0.0s
 => [nginx internal] load .dockerignore                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [nginx 1/3] FROM docker.io/library/nginx:1.21.3-alpine@sha256:1ff1364a1c4332341fc0a854820f1d50e90e11bb0b93eb5  0.0s
 => [nginx internal] load build context                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.18kB                                                                                0.0s
 => CACHED [nginx 2/3] RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [nginx 3/3] COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf                                          0.0s
 => [nginx] exporting to image                                                                                     0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                            0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:f79e9c332f6f83ef87923e7e7ac67321f70dc779e4e743d54fcd901634bca8ea                       0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/financecontroller-nginx
------
 > [client internal] load build context:
------
failed to solve: archive/tar: unknown file mode ?rwxr-xr-x

My docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.9"

services:
    api:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: ./docker/local/django/Dockerfile
        command: /start
        volumes:
            - .:/app
            - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
            - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
        expose:
            - "8000"
        env_file:
            - .env
        depends_on:
            - postgres-db
        networks:
            - finance-controller-react

    client:
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: ./docker/local/Dockerfile
        restart: on-failure
        volumes:
            - ./client:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        environment:
            - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
        networks:
            - finance-controller-react

    postgres-db:
        image: postgres:12.0-alpine
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
            - POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DB}
        networks:
            - finance-controller-react
        
    nginx:
        restart: always
        depends_on:
            - api
        volumes:
            - static_volume:/app/staticfiles
            - media_volume:/app/mediafiles
        build:
            context: ./docker/local/nginx
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - "8080:80"
        networks:
            - finance-controller-react

networks:
    finance-controller-react:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    postgres_data:
    static_volume:
    media_volume:

My dockerfile of the react (client)
ARG NODE_VERSION=16.14-alpine

FROM node:${NODE_VERSION} as node

FROM node as client-local-build

ARG APP_HOME=/app

WORKDIR ${APP_HOME}

COPY ./package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . ${APP_HOME}

CMD ["npm","start"]

My docker version in wsl:
Client:
 Cloud integration: v1.0.35+desktop.13
 Version:           26.1.1
 API version:       1.45
 Go version:        go1.21.9
 Git commit:        4cf5afa
 Built:             Tue Apr 30 11:48:43 2024
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Context:           default

Server: Docker Desktop 4.30.0 (149282)
 Engine:
  Version:          26.1.1
  API version:      1.45 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.21.9
  Git commit:       ac2de55
  Built:            Tue Apr 30 11:48:28 2024
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          1.6.31
  GitCommit:        e377cd56a71523140ca6ae87e30244719194a521
 runc:
  Version:          1.1.12
  GitCommit:        v1.1.12-0-g51d5e94
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.19.0
  GitCommit:        de40ad0

I am getting this error when building my containers in wsl:
docker compose up -d --build
I was expecting to successfully build my containers.
Edited added more info about the error
I am also running in the powershell in the wsl directory for better perfomance
